# request timeout??? how to use routerlink to navigate to 3 pages

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button (current page is: /abc) when click it navigate to [routerLink]="['/loading']"!
and I wanna after go /loading(finish page loading) then it goes to /animation link, then finally back to /result page.
how can I router to 3 links ?? 
do I need to create func in x.compent.ts ??

Comment: *"do I need to create func in x.compent.ts"* - yes

Comment: how can I execute it ? and in loading page it must be stay at least 3s or more than!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function and add the timeout for the loading route like this:-

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["lastpage"]);
}, 2000);
```